# on form submit failure url is changing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor form. Here is the useful part of the form.

```
<div id="forgotBox" style="display:none;" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 centerit">
<div class="col-md-12">


    @using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.user, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" } })<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.user)
        </div>

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.ErrorMsg))
        {
            <div class="form-group field-validation-error">
                @ViewBag.ErrorMsg
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }

    <div><a href="javascript:showLogin();">Login</a></div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller method it calls:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
            ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "";
            if (vm.confirmpass != vm.newPass)
            {
                //some error condition
                ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "Passwords do not match.";
            } else if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.user) ){
                 //code here for when you want to process when we have the userID
            } 


            return View("ForgotPassword", vm);
        }

    }
}
```

The `URL` when the user gets to this page is `example.org/login?user=123`

After the `return View("ForgotPassword", vm);` the url changes to

```
example.org/login/ForgotPassword
```

I would want it to stay `example.org/login?user=123` as the page was not successfully submitted and the URL params are being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the querystring value for user as route values.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Login", new { user = Request["user"] }))
{
}
```

When razor executes this code, it will render form tag with a querystring which includes the user key and the value.

```
<form action="/Login/ResetPassword?user=123" method="post"> 

</form>
```

Another option is to set the User property of your view model in the GET action method and the helper will generate the input element with value set to that value and when you submit it to post and when your code return to the View, the value will be there. (You will not have it in the querystring, but it will be in the request body when the form gets submitted.

Comment: are you saying i get rid of the `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

Comment: Why do you need that ? You need that attribute when you want to send a file (file upload)